# How do I get access to IMemoryCache in Program.cs in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I am in .Net 7.0 and in Program.cs we do not have any functions where there is a scope for dependency injection. The code is directly as follow:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel;
using WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore7;
using WordPressPCL;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


var emailConfig = builder.Configuration
        .GetSection("EmailConfiguration")
        .Get<EmailConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);

//builder.Services.AddSitemap();

builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

I want to get access to IMemoryCache here and want to store some data in there. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with something like

```cs
//Add memory cache
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
var app = builder.Build();

//Get memory cache instance
var cache = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();


//Set a value in cache
cache.Set("key", "value", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000)
});
```

## Simple working example

### Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
// Add memory cache
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
var app = builder.Build();

// Get memory cache instance
var cache = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();

//Set a value in cache
cache.Set("key", "value", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000)
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();


app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

### ExampleController.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace MemoryCache;

[Controller]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public ExampleController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    // GET
    [HttpGet("{key}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string key)
    {
        return Json(_cache.Get(key));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(string key, string value)
    {
        _cache.Set(key, value, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000)
        });
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

You could try it if you want
[Repo](https://github.com/dev-vinicius-andrade/memory-cache-example)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to register `MemoryCache` as a singleton. It has advantages, all application cache is in one place.

```
var memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache>(memoryCache);
```

Comment: IMemoryCache is already a singleton isn't it? Because once I store the object when the page refreshes the data is still available in the cache.

Comment: IMemoryCache is not a singleton by itself, it depends on how it is registered. MemoryCache can be registered as a singleton, it could be registered also transient, although this would not make much sense. It is possible to create multiple instances of MemoryCache with `new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions())`.

Comment: @KVSharma Let's be precise: `IMemoryCache` is an _interface_, not "a singleton". The DI system can resolve the registered service based on the interface you pass. Secondly, by default ASP.Net registers almost 300 services, but MemoryCache isn't one of them. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory).

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
public class MyMemoryCache
{
    public MyMemoryCache()
    {
        Cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        Cache.Set<string>("key", "val");
    }
    public MemoryCache Cache { get; } 
   
}


builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyMemoryCache>();


//get the value
var val=_myMemoryCache.Cache.Get("key");
```

follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-setsize-size-and-sizelimit-to-limit-cache-size)